# URL rewriting a specific directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, rewritecond

I want to rewrite the URL when receiving a request that is not a file and either for directory `subdir` or not a directory at all.

E.g.  (`!file`)  && ( (`subdir` ) | ( `!directory` ) )

Here's my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(subdir|subdir/.*).*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?request=$1 [QSA]
```

It works everywhere except for `subdir`. The rewrite condition to catch `subdir` is not working, it behaves as if there is no rewrite rule at all. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my fault. I'm an idiot. I'm not working at web root, I'm working within a subdirectory from the web root. Which means that:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(subdir|subdir/.*).*$ [OR]`

was looking in the wrong place. I should have done

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(subdir|subdir/.*).*$ [OR]`

or

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mydivision/(subdir|subdir/.*).*$ [OR]`